# Change button text on submit with velocity engine / java

Tags: java, html, velocity

So now I got a admin panel for my website I decided to try some small things but I am not getting there yet.

So whenever I disable or enable a user I get a nice good/bad notification saying what happened but ofcourse the button will stay the same. Is their a way to change this according to the function?

```
#parse("/velocity/layout.vm")
#@mainLayout()
<table id="adminPanel">
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Reset Password</th>
        <th>IsActive</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    #if($resetpassword)
        <p class="good notification">$msg.get("RESET_PASSWORD")</p>
    #elseif($blockuser)
        <p class="bad notification">$msg.get("BLOCK_USER")</p>
    #elseif($unblockuser)
        <p class="good notification">$msg.get("UNBLOCK_USER")</p>
    #elseif($deleteuser)
        <p class="bad notification">$msg.get("DELETE_USER")</p>
    #end
    #foreach($user in $users)
        #if($user.getIsadmin())
                <div class="col">
                    <tr>
                        <th>$user.getEmail()</th>
                        <th>$user.getFirstname() $user.getSurname()</th>
                        <th><form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post" value="reset">
                            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="$user.getEmail()">
                            <input type="submit"  value="Reset Password" disabled>
                        </form></th></th>
                        <th><form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post" value="block">
                            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="$$user.getEmail()">
                            <input type="submit"  value="IsActive" disabled>
                        </form></th></th>
                        <th><form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post" value="delete">
                            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="$user.getEmail()">
                            <input id="button" type="submit"  value="Delete" disabled>
                        </form></th>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            #else
                <div class="col">
                    <tr>
                        <th>$user.getEmail()</th>
                        <th>$user.getFirstname() $user.getSurname()</th>
                        <th><form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post" value="reset">
                            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="$user.getEmail()">
                            <input type="submit"  value="Reset Password">
                        </form></th></th>
                        <th><form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post" value="block">
                            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="$user.getEmail()">
                            <input type="submit"   value="Disable">
                        </form></th></th>
                        <th><form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post" value="delete">
                            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="$user.getEmail()">
                            <input type="submit"  value="Delete">
                        </form></th>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            #end
        #end
</table>
#end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very unclear in your question about what *buttons* you want the text to be changed. Since I see only two buttons in your code, I can recommend you to do something like this (assuming that the `User` object has enough details to know whether a user is blocked or not).

```
<input type="button" #if ($user.isBlocked()) value="Unblock" #else value="Block" #end>
```